# Xcode xip "The archive does not come from Apple"

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to install Xcode from xip, but when I try to open the .xip file I get the following error: 'The archive "Xcode.xip" does not come from Apple'

Comment: [Someone](https://talk.remobjects.com/t/the-archive-does-not-come-from-apple/10810) try to use `xar -xf Xcode.xip`, and `sudo tar zxvf Content`, however I failed at the 2nd step.

Answer (score 45):

The certificate used to sign the files probably expired. 
As a workaround, I managed to uncompress the xip file by setting my system date back to One year back.

Comment: for me one year before was too much because it was before the creation date but if I put the creation date of the file it works

Comment: Cool buddy your great .. ! :)

Comment: this is insanely brilliant :)

Answer (score 3):

As Ratnesh mentioned the signing certificate probably expired. Re-Downloading the .xip files from the [apple developer page](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Content` file with `xxd` it should look a bit like this;

```
00000000: 7062 7a78 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000  pbzx............
00000010: 0100 0000 0000 0000 0065 8a20 fd37 7a58  .........e. .7zX
00000020: 5a00 0000 ff12 d941 04c0 e293 9603 8080  Z......A........
00000030: 8008 2101 1600 0000 1fb3 f785 e41d 69ef  ..!...........i.
```

If so you have an lzma compressed file which gzip doesn't recognise.  Use this tool; [pbzx tool](https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/pbzx) to decompress the file and then you should find it is a cpio archive.

I just built this tool and are *un-cpio'ing* Xcode as I type.

Hopefully saves you having to download 5 Gig again just for an updated cert.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the system is connected to the internet (that you are trying to install xcode)

this fix for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).